# Flask SqlAlchemy many to many relationship only returns one result when accessing by relationship name

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, many-to-many

I have a simple many to many relationship using sql Alchemy like this:

```
file_favorites = db.Table('file_favorites',
                              db.Column('file_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('file.id')),
                              db.Column('user_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
                              db.Column('created_at', db.DateTime(), default=db.func.now()))


    class File(db.Model, helpers.ModelMixin):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
        name = db.Column(db.Unicode, nullable=False)
        description = db.Column(db.Unicode, nullable=False)
        created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime(), default=func.now())
        last_updated = db.Column(db.DateTime(), default=func.now(), onupdate=func.now())

        user_id = db.Column('user_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False, index=True)
        user = db.relationship('User')

        favorited_by = db.relationship('User', secondary=file_favorites, lazy='dynamic')   

        def is_favorite_of(self, user):
            query = File.query
            query = query.join(file_favorites)
            query = query.filter(file_favorites.c.file_id == self.id)
            query = query.filter(file_favorites.c.user_id == user.id)
            return query.count() > 0

        def favorite(self, user):
            if not self.is_favorite_of(user):
                self.favorited_by.append(user)

        def unfavorite(self, user):
            if self.is_favorite_of(user):
                self.favorited_by.remove(user)
```

I would expect that accessing the favorited_by property would result in a query that tries to return a list of users that have favorited this file. However, it seems that the query is only accessing the FIRST user to have favorited this file. I'm puzzled by this, and expect that I don't correctly understand sqlalchemy relationships. Here is the result i'm experiencing:

```
def create_model(model_class, *args, **kwargs):
    model = model_class(*args, **kwargs)
    db.session.add(model)
    db.session.commit()
    return model    

def test_favorited_by(self):
        user = create_model(User, username='user', email='user@user.net', password='password')
        user1 = create_model(User, username='user1', email='user1@user.net', password='password')
        user2 = create_model(User, username='user2', email='user2@user.net', password='password')


        file = create_model(File, name='file', description='a description', user=user)

        file.favorite(user1)
        file.favorite(user)
        file.favorite(user2)
        db.session.commit()
        print file.favorited_by
```

results in this query:

```
SELECT "user".id AS user_id, "user".email AS user_email, "user".username AS user_username, "user".password AS user_password, "user".active AS user_active, "user".last_login_at AS user_last_login_at, "user".current_login_at AS user_current_login_at, "user".last_login_ip AS user_last_login_ip, "user".current_login_ip AS user_current_login_ip, "user".login_count AS user_login_count, "user".last_updated AS user_last_updated, "user".created_at AS user_created_at 
FROM "user", file_favorites 
WHERE :param_1 = file_favorites.file_id AND "user".id = file_favorites.user_id
```

Which ultimately returns user1, if the order is switched, the first user to favorite the file will always be the user returned.

Comment: What happens if you print `file.favorited_by.all()`?

Comment: Printing file.favorited_by.all() returns:
[<app.models.users.User object at 0x10693b910>]
A single user object in a list, which matches user1, the first user to favorite.

Comment: What does `File.favorite` look like? My guess is it's doing something like `self.favorited_by = user` rather than `self.favorited_by.append(user)`.

Comment: I added the favorite, unfavorite and is favorite of methods to the code for clarity. I am using append, and not equals. Using is_favorite_of(user) returns true, which seems like the relationship table is being correctly populated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with `is_favorite_of`. It doesn't incorporate `user` into the check. You need to add another filter.

```
def is_favorite_of(self, user):
    query = File.query
    query = query.join(file_favorites)
    query = query.filter(file_favorites.c.file_id == self.id)
    query = query.filter(file_favorites.c.user_id == user.id)
    return query.count() > 0
```

Alternatively, this whole function can be simplified to:

```
def is_favorite_of(self, user):
    return user in self.favorited_by
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I like your simplification as well! The funny thing about it is, the line was originally there, I think I removed it accidentally with a hotkey.